# Implicit Intent for show keyboard

Tags: android, android-intent, layout, keyboard

I need to know how show a keyboard without show the TextView, and I had thought of using Implicit Intents, but I dont see any example.

I currently I have this code:
For layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/keyboardPassword"
    android:inputType="numberPassword|textPassword"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userListing"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/keyboardPassword" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

For class:

```
private void showKeyboard() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }

    });
}
private void registerKeyboardClickCallback() {
    final TextView keyboard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyboardPassword);
    keyboard.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                //action
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

With this code the line of TextView appears, and if I hide the textView, the Keyboard never show

Thanks! Greetings!

Comment: off the topic.. may I know the reason for showing Keyboard without the textviews?? The keyboard will appear when there is a focus on the View(TextView or EditText). So if there is no focus android will automatically hide the keyboard.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell me bad, I wanted to not appear the line